# Prestashop 1.7 getProductLink TPL

Tags: task-parallel-library, prestashop

sorry for my english could I am of french descent

Prestashop 1.7 getProductLink TPL
some time ago I developed a module for my site, in the Tpl I get the links with this method

```
<a href="{$link->getProductLink($ViewProduct.id_product, $ViewProduct.link_rewrite, null, null, null, null)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
    {$ViewProduct.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
</a>
```

today I'm passing on prestashop 1.7 the problem and when I open a link, mine and in this way

***art/3-affiche-encadree-the-best-is-yet-to-come.html***

but prestashop 1.7 offers me a redirection on

***art/3-13-affiche-encadree-the-best-is-yet-to-come.html***

on the seo page of my presta I have this
 
*{Category: / {id}} {-: id_product_attribute} - {{rewrite} -: ean13} .html*

here I do not want to edit I just want to get the exact links link_rewrite

Comment: (I reply in french, as it will be more convinient)
En français, simplement, les deux liens que vous proposez sont identiques. Pouvez vous réexpliquer le problème en francais ci dessous ?

Comment: oui, mdr j'ai, mis le meme lien, voila le lien de mon module art/3-affiche-encadree-the-best-is-yet-to-come.html et celui que prestashop me propose   art/3-13-affiche-encadree-the-best-is-yet-to-come.html

Comment: j'essaye de récupérer le link_rewrite comme prestashop mais je sais pas quoi faire pour l'adapter

Comment: The problem is that function `getProductLink` returns url `art/3-affiche-encadree-the-best-is-yet-to-come.html` but when you open this URL it redirects to `art/3-13-affiche-encadree-the-best-is-yet-to-come.html`?

Comment: yes exactly, I solved the problem, thanks to you       
<a href="{$link->getProductLink($ViewProduct.id_product, $ViewProduct.link_rewrite, $ViewProduct.category_rewrite, null, null, null, $ViewProduct.id_lang)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$ViewProduct.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" style="text-decoration: none;">